# Problem with QPushButton icons appearing PySide6

Tags: python, python-3.x, icons, pyside6, qpushbutton

I am experiencing a problem with displaying button icons in the QDialog window. This problem occurs when trying to run the window from the main file, knowing that the QDialog window file is not in the same path as the main file.

This is the code to import the design from the `__init__.py` file inside WindowAdd

```
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile, QDate, Qt, QRect, QPropertyAnimation, QEasingCurve ,QTimer
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QPushButton, QDialog, QListWidgetItem, QCompleter
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from .ui_Add_Item import Ui_Form
from Lib import database3
from datetime import datetime
from functools import partial
import random
import time
import os
import sys

class CustomListWidgetItem(QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, text, hidden_data):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.hidden_data = hidden_data

class Widgets(QDialog, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, page=""):
        super(Widgets, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Widgets()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

I tried to execute a local code inside WindowAdd and the icons appeared very normally without the slightest problem, but when I exit to the main file the problem returns again.

These are the libraries and the most important codes used inside the `main.py`

```
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QMenu, QGraphicsBlurEffect
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide6.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QAction, QTextOption, QIcon
from ui_Style3 import Ui_Form
from WindowAdd import Widgets as WindowAdd2
from Lib import database3
from datetime import datetime
import random
import sys

class Widgets(QWidget,Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widgets, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        #Title window name and icon
        self.setWindowTitle("Business record")  #Name title
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("path30.png")) #Icon title

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Widgets()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Just for your information, I use the design files from the Qt Designer program to download the ready-made design files. The `main.py` file and the `__init__.py` file are files to control the design files and execute instructions.

Comment: File paths are always relative to the *working directory* (unless they are absolute). The common suggestion is to always get the absolute path of such resources dynamically, considering their relative path to the file that needs them (aka, `__file__`). Use `os.path` and pathlib for that.

Comment: @musicamante Sorry, I did not understand the idea much. Can you explain these points you talked about more clearly?

Comment: `"path30.png"` is a relative path, meaning that it requires a "context" to find it. That *context* is normally the [working directory](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of a process, which normally is from where the program is run. Since you're not familiar with these concepts, let's suppose (but I may be wrong) that you're on Windows, you have your main script `main.py` in ```C:\myproject\``` along with its icons, and the dialog in ```C:\myproject\dialogs\```: if you run the main script from its directory, the *working dir* will be `C:\myproject` and the dialog script will try to »

Comment: » retrieve those icons from there, because a *relative path* is used. So, `path30.png` won't be searched as `C:\myproject\dialogs\path30.png`, but `C:\myproject\path30.png`. If you want to use relative paths (and you should), you should always use them along with the actual path of the file/script that is using them. I strongly suggest you to read more about [paths](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths), as knowing their differences and understanding how to work with them is a mandatory knowledge in programming, especially when using interpreters such as Python.

Comment: @musicamante I understood what you meant, but this is not what I meant. I am sorry if I did not explain my problem well, but the problem is not related to `path30.png`, but the problem is that when I press the error button, for example, and a pop-up message appears alerting you of the error. I programmed the pop-up message interface and it contains some Icons but they do not appear